# Npm run is not working inside crontab (cronjob)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, npm, cron, nuxt.js

I want to use Makefile and shellscript to generate and render static content using nuxt.

**Makefile**:

```
deploy-content: ## Generate content using nuxt
       @echo $(/bin/bash -c cd /var/www/nuxt; npm run --prefix /var/www/nuxt generate)
```

**render.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

# start generating content in background
make deploy-content > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**Crontab -e** :) :

```
# Midnight 2 am
0 2 * * *        cd /var/www/generate/ && make deploy-content > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**Please also consider following things:**

- *render.sh* has *+x* permission.
- *Makefile* and *render.sh* are located in different directory ( not
  inside /var/www/nuxt ).
- When I run shellscript from shell it works fine, but not works from crontab.
- I also tried to put npm commands in crontab straigtaway. ( not worked )

Can someone help me, Pleeeeeeeeeease? May be I missed something and did not realize. :)

Many thanks in advance, Cheers!

Comment: Does the execution run under a user or group different than owner? rwx------
What is your file permission? Perhaps just try rwxrwxrwx for testing purpose and see if it works.

Comment: It's running under same user/group and also from shell its executed perfectly but not from crontab @Elijah

Comment: I'm not really familiar with CRON but most things I run into with UNIX are permission based issues.
I would try for testing purpose to just change the files & folders to rwxrwxrwx. Then try the cron again.

Comment: Curious. Was it a permission issue or is the problem still present?

Comment: Can you provide `render.sh` ? Is it the only line from the script ?
If it is, it might be related to the fact that you're running it in background, so it works where you're doing it from shell which stays open after script execution; but it doesn't work from crontab which might close the "session" after running the script.

Comment: Can you provide the logs happening after editing your crontab with `* * * * * /absolute/path/to/npm > /some/log/file.txt 2>&1` ?

Comment: @Elijah I tried to give full permission rwxrwxrwx, It did not work.

Comment: @snwfdhmp I execute the same command from a shell. And I keep track of it using `ps -aux`. And also the fact that content is generated after the successful execution of that command.

Comment: @HasmukhMistry please provide the information I requested so we can help you finding a solution

Comment: @snwfdhmp I will try to get the logs from the cronjob.

Comment: @HasmukhMistry In order to see any kind of script logs you will need to remove the `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` part

Comment: In your crontab try using the absolute path (eg. `/usr/bin/make deploy-content ...` instead of just `make deploy-content`). Also where is the `Makefile`, perhaps point to it's absolute directory as well.

Comment: @l'L'l These I already tried before. Somehow, none of them were helping.

Comment: @snwfdhmp I used absolute path to npm to start generation. Also redirecting output to file shows compilation errors. Although from CLI it works well without any errors.

Comment: Could you post the type of error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

After 3 hours of struggle i found that the environment for a script that is triggered from crontab is very different from the environment where its called directly from the shell. You can observe it by doing `printenv` command from the shell and from the crontab.

The way to resolve the issue is to copy the PATH variable for the user (by doing `printenv` from shell) and paste the same content at the start of the shell script that is getting triggered by cronjob.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest case that works:

Crontab

```
* * * * *        /usr/bin/make -C /var/www/generate/ > /tmp/log.txt
```

Makefile (/var/www/generate/Makefile)

```
deploy-content:
    /bin/bash -c "cd /var/www/nuxt/; npm ls"
```

Output should then be at

```
cat /tmp/log.txt
```

Comment: This is something different then I am looking for. THanks anyway.

Comment: The only difference should be you changing the 'npm ls' to 'npm run --prefix /var/www/nuxt generate' to confirm if it actually runs. Then updating the time when you have confirmed it works

Comment: Most common reason for cron failure is your PATH and environment are not set. try setting your PATH or sourcing your profile. Also you can see why the command is failing if you get rid of the "> /dev/null 2&1".  Cron will then email the output/error.

Comment: Your cron syntax all testing fine to me.